# Minibuffer text alignment problem

Tags: minibuffer, echo-area

The text that is displayed in my mini buffer is misaligned, like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agyr5.jpg Specially all the columns are garbled, like its trying to wrap text? How can I make it so that they are aligned properly?

Comment: I suspect the issue is you're using a variable-width font. If you switch it to a monospace font, do you still see the issue?

Comment: I changed to a monospace font and the issue went away. So it seems variable width fonts cause the issue(I was using the Input Font)

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer. And you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

So I changed emacs font to a monospace font and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Mark your answer as the solution once you're able to.